# Agregar elementos no repetidos de un array otro t cambiar estatus

Tags: javascript

Buenas a todos comunidad tengo un detalle que no he podido resolver. tengo dos `array` con los siguientes datos:

**array 1:**

```
{
id_proyecto_programa: 110, 
id_programa: 38, 
activo: true
},
{
id_proyecto_programa: 111, 
id_programa: 39, 
activo: true
}
```

**array 2:**

```
{
id_proyecto_programa: 110, 
id_programa: 38, 
activo: true
},
```

Lo que deseo es que esos dos arreglos se sumen o sea el primer `array` si no esta repetido se agregue los valores al segundo arreglo y si no estaba en el primer `array` que su activo cambie a false.

Así:

**array 2:**

```
{
id_proyecto_programa: 110, 
id_programa: 38, 
activo: true
},
{
id_proyecto_programa: 111, 
id_programa: 39, 
activo: false
}
```

Hasta ahora tengo lo 2 arreglos con esa estructura pero no se como hacerle para hacer eso que les comento. Si me pueden ayudar se los super agradeceria muchisimo.

Actualizacion:

```
const program = jsonprograma_modificar.concat(this.m_programa_educativo_general)

let result = program.filter((item,index)=>{
            return program.indexOf(item) === index;
          })
```

en program concateno los dos arreglos y hasta ahi todo bien, en el filter deseo eliminar el repetido de id_programa si por ejemplo se repeti el id_programa: 38 dos veces que solo quede una vez. pero como no estaba en el segundo arreglo antes de sumar este valor que se cambie el estatus activo de true a false.

Perdon no soy bueno explicando

Comment: Agrega lo que has intentado.

Comment: @Lobos listo amigo, espero me puedas ayudar, te lo super agradeceria muchisimo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si lo he entendido bien, creo que puedes lograr hacerlo utilizando `array.map` en combinación con `array.some`. Hecha un vistazo:

```js
const programsA = [
  {
    id_proyecto_programa: 110, 
    id_programa: 38, 
    activo: true,
  },
  {
    id_proyecto_programa: 111, 
    id_programa: 39, 
    activo: true,
  }
];

const programsB = [
  {
    id_proyecto_programa: 110, 
    id_programa: 38, 
    activo: true,
  },
];

const mergePrograms = (programsA, programsB) => programsA.map((pA) => ({
  ...pA,
  activo: programsB.some((pB) => pB.id_proyecto_programa === pA.id_proyecto_programa),
}));

const mergedPrograms = mergePrograms(programsA, programsB);

console.log(mergedPrograms);
```